# Could not send e-mail using WildFly 17 running on Ubuntu 18.04 / Windows 10

Tags: java, ubuntu, network-programming, smtp, wildfly

I am using java, and wilfly 17 running on ubuntu 18 and would like to send an e-mail via localhost / a remote host, i.e. gmail, using this server.
I have implemented the solution described in

[send mail via localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397274/send-email-wildfly-localhost)

and then tried implementing the solution described in

[send mail via remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613406/com-sun-mail-util-mailconnectexception-couldnt-connect-to-host-port-localhos)

But, unfortunately, in both cases I am getting one and the same exception

```
    Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at javax.mail.api@1.6.2//com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209)
    at javax.mail.api@1.6.2//com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
```

respectively:

```
    Couldn't connect to host, port: mail.google.com, 25; timeout -1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: mail.google.com, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at javax.mail.api@1.6.2//com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209)
    at javax.mail.api@1.6.2//com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
    at javax.mail.api@1.6.2//javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
```

Regarding allowing outbound connections on my Ubuntu system, I have allowed all outbound connections as described in

[allow inbound/ outbound connections Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I just have tried sending an email through WildFly 17 running on Windows 10, but I am getting the same exception as above:

```
    (default task-6) Couldn't connect to host, port: mail.google.com, 25; timeout -1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: mail.google.com, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at javax.mail.api@1.6.2//com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209)
    at javax.mail.api@1.6.2//com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
    at javax.mail.api@1.6.2//javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
```

Comment: Google doesn't allow unencrypted smtp traffic, and you aren't running a smtp server on your ubuntu. `sudo apt install mailutils`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it seems you haven't read my whole question. Part (1) does not concern google at all, but it is still not working;  And, it since I am using WildFly, I do have a smtp server, don't I ?

Comment: 1) "mail.google.com" **is** google. 2) No. SMTP == Simple Mail Transport Protocol. Wildfly is **not** a SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your comments!

Ultimately I solved the problem by following exactly the steps listed here:

[Configure WildFly to send eMails](http://khozzy.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-send-mails-from-jboss-wildfly.html)

then, after having recieved the exception

```
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8
```

I logged on into my gmail account, on behalf of which I wanted to send e-mails, and enabled the option in this link:

[Enable less secure apps gmail](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

Then I tested my solution on both Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 and it worked in both cases!